# Missing the last closing bracket in regular expression

Tags: regex, string

From the below string

```
lookup('CONTACT','CON_LKP','LKP_TAB1.COUNTRY_CD')||lookup('CONTACT','CON_LKP','LKP_TAB2.OBJECTIVE')||$country_cd$
```

to extract the lookup function I use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(lookup\\([^)]*)\\)");
```

But this function is reurning the match excluding the last closing bracket ')'. Like its returning

```
lookup('CONTACT','CON_LKP','LKP_TAB1.COUNTRY_CD'
```

Where I am making the mistake. By the way I know very little in regular expression. So my question may be very silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the line to

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(lookup\\([^)]*\\))");
```

You need to include the end bracket `\\)` in the matching group too.

Code:

```
shadyabhi@archlinux /tmp $ cat RegExpTest.java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegExpTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "lookup('CONTACT','CON_LKP','LKP_TAB1.COUNTRY_CD')||lookup('CONTACT','CON_LKP','LKP_TAB2.OBJECTIVE')||$country_cd$";

        String p = "(lookup\\([^)]*\\))";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
shadyabhi@archlinux /tmp $ javac RegExpTest.java 
shadyabhi@archlinux /tmp $ java RegExpTest 
lookup('CONTACT','CON_LKP','LKP_TAB1.COUNTRY_CD')
shadyabhi@archlinux /tmp $
```